# Integrating PayPal for customized website

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am new to payment processing gateways. I am basically working on a driving school website where I am trying to integrate paypal to accept payments. I searched a lot but what I cannot figure out is that there are two ways of achieving payments through Paypal.

1. Using a direct amount with the hidden html fields.
2. Sending multiple payments as cart option to paypal.

What my system has is that there is a form that requires the user to select from a list of different packages in a select control. All the package information is stored in the database.

**PROBLEM:**

What i am trying to achieve is that whatever package is selected through the select control, the corresponding amount value of that particular package is fetched from the database, sent to Paypal and in return, I get the transaction ID to email the customer for successful registration of the package.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you are using the correct PayPal product. For the type of transaction you are trying to make, you need to use one of their business tools. You will obviously need to review the features of all of their business products and select the one that works best for you. I don't want to suggest which one because I don't know all of your requirements, but if you check out the [PayPal Developer Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/), you will be able to see the various features of their products and how to use them. This will help to figure out which product you will want to use.